# Autofit image cardview in Recycler view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am working on `RecyclerView` to display the images in `CardView`.

I use `GridLayoutManager` and i have specified 3 items in each row:

`mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context,3);`

**Problem:** Images are `perfectly fitted` in the card view in my testing device.But if i test it in devices smaller than my testing device, right side of the cardview is getting `trimmed`.

If i reduce the width in the cardview to suite the small devices,then i could see more margin in the right side in larger screens.

**My Question:**

How to design my xml layout to work for both small and large screens? i.e i don't want the right side edges of the cardview getting trimmed in smaller devices.

**Grid_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="0.01dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#E7A423"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_layout"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**RecyclerView.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/seperator"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:padding="10dp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from size of your `CardView`. Your `cardView` in small screen is bigger than `RecyclerView`'s item. Your `reyclerView's item width` are calculated based on `recyclerWidth/yourSpanCount` (it's 3 in your code). So, I suggest that you can use difference size for you `cardView` for difference screen-size. 

 To archive that, you should not declare specific dimen in your xml: `android:layout_height="120dp"`. You can change like: `android:layout_height="@dimen/imageWidth"`.

then you can declare `dimens` in extra folder like: `values-xlarge/dimens.xml`, `values-small/dimens.xml` or even with `smallest width` if I do not missremember.

Answer (score 0):

this is may be help you => [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

you can use multiple dimens.xml for different devices